# database table handler many to many

Tags: sql

So, I am 2 tables, ex table1 with #primkey1, entity1 and table2 with #primkey2, entity2. I want to link this two table, but I have a many to many relationship. Can you give me te sql statement that create the third for many to many handler.

Comment: you add a junction table between your existing tables, with foreign keys to your existing tables - and add a row into the junction table to describe each of the many to many relationships

Answer (score 0):

You need a junction table to relate individual rows between the two tables, so you end up with:-

```
table1
key    entity
1      haddock
2      tuna
3      shark

table2
key    entity
a      north
b      south
c      east

junctiontable
key1    key2
1       a
1       b
2       a
3       b
3       c
```